# Javascript slice from reverse

Tags: javascript, html

I want to slice the javascript variable in the given condition.

The condition is if the variable is of length 12 it should slice as 2,6,4 and if it is of length 11 it should slice as 2,5,4. How can i slice this.

**Here is what i have tried.**

Code :

```
var new_no   = "("+phone_no.slice(0,2)+")-"+phone_no.slice(2,7)+"-"+phone_no.slice(7,11);
```

How can i make the length checking condition and slice according to my given condition ?

Comment: You mean you want to remove the elements from an array?

Comment: No, i won't if the length is 12, it will mask as 2,6,4 and if length is 11 it will mask as 2,5,4

Comment: Ow you mean to say if the lenght of the number string is 12 you want to make it example if `123456789011` convert it to `12-345678-9011`  is this what you are trying to achieve ?

Comment: Consider using [*substr*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.5.4.15) instead of *slice* as it's compatible with older browsers and takes the same arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use `.length` to check the length of the number and then two simple conditions will do the trick:

```
var phone_no = "123456789878";
if(phone_no.length === 11)
    var new_no   = "("+phone_no.slice(0,2)+")-"+phone_no.slice(2,7)+"-"+phone_no.slice(7,11);
else if(phone_no.length === 12)
    var new_no   = "("+phone_no.slice(0,2)+")-"+phone_no.slice(2,8)+"-"+phone_no.slice(8,12);
else
    alert('Invalid Number');
```

**[See the DEMO here](http://jsfiddle.net/q6gb74tp/)**

Answer (score 1):

You can make the middle slice conditional:

```
var midEnd = phone_no.length == 11? 7 : 8;

var new_no = "("+phone_no.slice(0,2)+")-"+phone_no.slice(2,midEnd)+"-"+phone_no.slice(midEnd);
```

If you don't supply a second parameter, it will slice to the end. Though for greater browser compatibility I'd use [*substr*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.5.4.15) instead:

```
var new_no = '(' + phone_no.substr(0,2) + ')-' + 
             phone_no.substr(2,midEnd) +
             '-' + phone_no.substr(midEnd);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function preparePhoneNo(num) {
    return '(' + num.slice(0, 2) + ')-' + num.slice(2, -4) +  '-' + num.slice(-4);
}

var phone_no = "123465789012";
var new_no = preparePhoneNo(phone_no);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my take,  I would use `substr`

```
var phone_no = '12345678901'; 
var midGroup = phone_no.length == 11 ? 5 : 6;
var new_no = "("+phone_no.substr(0,2)+")-"+phone_no.substr(2,midGroup)+"-"+phone_no.substr(midGroup + 2);
alert(new_no);
```