# Phone Number slice and mask

Tags: javascript

This is the continuity of the Question [Javascript slice from reverse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25967129/java-script-slice-from-reverse)

As i am new to javascript. I am unable to give the condition in proper place. Help with this please.

If the variable new_no

```
var phones = labels.phones;
phone_nums = phones.split(",");

for(var l=0; l<phone_nums.length; l++)
{
var new_no   = "("+phone_nums[l].slice(0,2)+")-"+phone_nums[l].slice(2,6)+"-"+phone_nums[l].slice(6,11);
list +="<li>"+ new_no+"<a class='removno' >x</a><input type=\"hidden\" name=\"phoneno[]\" value=\""+phone_nums[l]+"\" /></li>";
}
```

How can i insert the below condition here :

```
if(phone_no.length === 11)
    var new_no   = "("+phone_no.slice(0,2)+")-"+phone_no.slice(2,7)+"-"+phone_no.slice(7,11);
else if(phone_no.length === 12)
    var new_no   = "("+phone_no.slice(0,2)+")-"+phone_no.slice(2,8)+"-"+phone_no.slice(8,12);
else
    alert('Invalid Number');
```

Comment: Just insert it in?..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this  it's shorter and neater same result

****EDIT****

I updated the logic to fit your needs

```
var new_no = "";

var phones = labels.phones;
phone_nums = phones.split(",");
var list = ""; 
for(p_index in phone_nums){
   var phone_no = phone_nums[p_index];
   var pLength = phone_no.length;

   if(pLength == 11 || pLength == 12){
         var midGroup = pLength == 11 ? 5 : 6;

         new_no = "("+phone_no.substr(0,2)+")-"+phone_no.substr(2,midGroup)+"-"+phone_no.substr(midGroup + 2);
         list +="<li>"+ new_no+"<a class='removno' >x</a><input type=\"hidden\" name=\"phoneno[]\" value=\""+phone_no+"\" /></li>";
   } else {
      console.log('Invalid Number  :: ' + phone_no);
   }  
}
```

Assuming that `labels.phones` contains `'123456789011,110987654321'` This will output below

```
<li>(12)-345678-9011<a class='removno' >x</a><input type="hidden" name="phoneno[]" value="123456789011" /></li>
<li>(11)-098765-4321<a class='removno' >x</a><input type="hidden" name="phoneno[]" value="110987654321" /></li>
```

Here is a demo http://jsfiddle.net/cdahh64c/

Comment: i will check it and convey in few min\

Comment: by the way `labels.phones`contains multiple set of phone numbers?  If so I need to redo my code a little bit

Comment: But it is not returning the number with 11 digits, i am checking on it

Comment: @BIz Are you sure it's not working check demo it's working for both 11 and 12 digit number http://jsfiddle.net/cdahh64c/

Comment: could you please create a chat room for this pls

Comment: I have pasted a link to a demo did you see it. It works for booth 11 and 12 digit

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61675/discussion-between-andrex-and-biz).

Answer (score 0):

You just need to insert the code inside the for loop. You'll need a bit more work if you need to add to the list only if the number is valid.

```
var phones = labels.phones;
phone_nums = phones.split(",");

for(var l=0; l<phone_nums.length; l++)
{
  if(phone_no.length === 11)
   var new_no   = "("+phone_no.slice(0,2)+")-"+phone_no.slice(2,7)+"-"+phone_no.slice(7,11);
  else if(phone_no.length === 12)
   var new_no   = "("+phone_no.slice(0,2)+")-"+phone_no.slice(2,8)+"-"+phone_no.slice(8,12);
  else
   alert('Invalid Number');

  if(phone_no.length === 11 || phone_no.length === 12)
   list +="<li>"+ new_no+"<a class='removno' >x</a><input type=\"hidden\" name=\"phoneno[]\" value=\""+phone_nums[l]+"\" /></li>";
}
```